PUN 2で特定のプレイヤーにのみオブジェクトを表示させたい
私はPhoton Unity Networking 2 (PUN 2) を使用してマルチプレイヤーゲームを開発中です。ゲーム内でプレイヤーがトリガーを押した（触れた）時、そのプレイヤーにのみ特定のオブジェクト (objectToShow) を表示したいと考えています。しかし、現在の実装では、あるプレイヤーがトリガーを押しても、全プレイヤーにそのオブジェクトが表示されてしまいます。
問題
以下のコードは、プレイヤーがトリガー領域に入ると、objectToShow を表示するように設計されています。しかし、このスクリプトでは objectToShow が全プレイヤーに表示されてしまい、意図した動作と異なります。
using UnityEngine;

public class instructionTrigger : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject objectToShow;
    private bool trigger_once = false;

    void Start()
    {
        if (objectToShow == null)
        {
            Debug.LogError("objectToShow is not set!");
        }
        else
        {
            objectToShow.SetActive(false);
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (trigger_once)
        {
            Debug.Log("Trigger already activated once.");
            return;
        }

        Debug.Log("Collision detected with: " + other.gameObject.name);

        objectToShow.SetActive(true);
        trigger_once = true;
    }
}

このスクリプトを使用していると、自分の手でボタンを押しても、他のプレイヤーから見ても衝突が検知されており、結果として全プレイヤーに objectToShow が見えてしまうと考えております。
PUN2でこの問題を解決する方法やアドバイスがあれば教えてください。
よろしくお願いします。


ゲーム内でプレイヤーがトリガーを押した（触れた）時、そのプレイヤーにのみ特定のオブジェクト (objectToShow) を表示したい

衝突したオブジェクトが自分かどうかを判別することで実現できませんか？
プレイヤーには、PhotonView がアタッチしてあると思うので、衝突したオブジェクト経由で、その PhotonView を取得し、PhotonView.IsMine で自分が生成したかを確認し、自分の場合は、処理を実行することで実現できると思います。
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (trigger_once)
    {
        Debug.Log("Trigger already activated once.");
        return;
    }

    Debug.Log("Collision detected with: " + other.gameObject.name);

    // 衝突したオブジェクトの PhotonView を取得する
    // この例では、衝突したオブジェクトの親に PhotonView がアタッチしてある
    // 衝突したオブジェクトに PhotonView を取得する関数を定義するのが良い
    var otherPhotonView = other.gameObject.transform.parent.gameObject.GetComponent<PhotonView>();

    if (otherPhotonView != null && otherPhotonView.IsMine)
    {
        // 衝突したオブジェクトが自分の場合にのみ処理を実行
        objectToShow.SetActive(true);
        trigger_once = true;
    }
}


hiromasa masuda 様
ご提示していただいた方法で無事に実装ができました．
いつもありがとうございます！
